# Can't simultaneously have superscripted footnotes in text and footnote counter not cycling back to 1 with each chapter

Tags: footnotes, counters, superscripts, chngcntr

I want my footnotes superscripted in the text and numbered continuously in the text of my book from 1 to n, without restarting at 1 with each chapter. In the MWE below, if I comment out the \chngcntr and \counterwithout lines, the footnotes in the text are superscripted, but renumbered from 1 with each new chapter. If I keep the two lines active, then the footnotes are not superscripted in the text, but they are continuous (from 1-4). This is true for LaTeX distributions texlive 2014, texlive 2017, and TeX/texbin.

MWE

```latex
\documentclass{cambridge6A}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter} 


\begin{document}

\chapter{Paragraph 1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\footnote{This is foornote 1.} get egestas purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi. \footnote{This is foornote 2.}

\chapter{Paragraph 2}

Commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus.\footnote{This is foornote 3.} Eget egestas purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi.\footnote{This is foornote 4.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Where can we have the `cambridge6A` class file?

Comment: How do I upload the file? Should I just cut and paste as a comment?

Comment: Download cls file here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mpi9jt71ym1tnpt/cambridge6A.cls?dl=0

Comment: I took at look at the cls file and I saw the following (see below). I wonder if this is the problem. % reset on chapters
\@addtoreset{footnote}{chapter}
\long\def\@makefntext#1{\raggedright\@setpar{\@@par\@tempdima \hsize
 \advance\@tempdima-\@footindent
 \parshape \@ne \@footindent \@tempdima}\par
 \noindent \hbox to \z@{\hss\@thefnmark\enskip}#1}

Comment: Solved! I commented out the \@addtoreset{footnote}{chapter} and now I have continuously numbered, super-scripted, text footnotes throughout. Thanks for leading me to the cls file.